# Shell command to send file via Bluetooth on Mac OS X

Tags: shell, macos, bluetooth

Is there any way to use a shell script under Mac OS X to send a file via Bluetooth ?

PS: Anyone having a solution under Windows is welcome too...

Comment: I'm wishywashy on sending this to SuperUser. Care to say something about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `cp` once you mount the device using the FUSE-based [OpenOBEX](http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/) filesystem. [OBEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBEX) is a protocol used by some bluetooth devices. (here's an [article](http://simbot.wordpress.com/2006/06/04/bluetooth-fuse-obexfs-under-debian/) on using it in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

No, but it would not be too hard to write your own command line tool using the IOBluetooth OBEX APIs. ;)